# Import existing asp.net website on Visual Studio for mac

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web

I'm working as frontend developer in a company which uses asp.net for its website. I usually work on mac and I need to setup my localhost to work on the website, but something's wrong with the project. They provided me the folder with all the files (aspx, aspx.cs, dll etc), and I'm supposed to build my own solution file. Visual Studio for macOS doesn't give me the possibility to create an empty website project (VS for pc does), or maybe I'm selecting the wrong entry. What am I supposed to do?

I tried to select Empty ASP.NET Web project, but It doesn't work, all the vars and methods from aspx pages are not detected in aspx.cs. Same with Web Form. I can't set up anything and the solution is not working.
Everyone at the company uses Windows and they can't help me.
What I have to do to import it in the right way? 
I'd like to use VS Code if it's possible. This is the first time with asp.net.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think vs for MAC used .net core web sites not the classic asp.net

Comment: And I can't import it in any way, right?

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is that *ASP.NET Web Forms* is obsolete. I guess they stopped to support such type of solution a long time ago, only critical crushes. If you really want to use mac for *ASP.NET Web Forms* you should install ***Parallels VM*** with ***Windows 10*** and ***Visual Studio*** on board.

Comment: Do you suggest to migrate the website to another format before publishing? I'm getting mad trying to import the project in VS or Code.

Comment: No, if you have working project on ASP.NET Web Forms, if you want to work with it and don't want to upgrade the platform I suggest to install virtual machine and use Visual Studio under Windows. Because this guys from ex-Xamarin Studio (now Visual Studio for Mac) hardly ever will fix something for ASP.NET Web Forms template...I bet they in critical maintenance mode now for this template.

Comment: @malvibra, "all the vars and methods from aspx pages are not detected in aspx.cs. Same with Web Form." - why they don't provide you a whole solution? I guess there will be the same problem in Windows, especially if you're new in Web Forms, there may be some classes which is referencing on some library in the solution and you don't know it.

Comment: I tried to import the project in VS for Windows without:
- solution
- web.config
- .csproj 
and the restore worked. There are some warnings, but nothing compared to the errors in VS for mac. 
Probably the only way is to use Windows.